# How to add new languages to AEM Tags for localisation?

Tags: localization, aem

The AEM Tags console allows localised titles to be added to each tag.

[image: Editing an AEM tag. There's a list of languages visible on the right-hand side listing English, German, Spanish, French, etc.]

However, this list is missing some of the locale codes I need to support. What is the source of this list? There is a basic configuration for available languages under `/libs/wcm/core/resources/languages` but it contains a lot more entries than this dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dropdown is handled by the script under `/libs/cq/tagging/gui/components/tagedit/languagepicker/render.jsp`

The original source of the list of tags, as per this JSP, is the `com.day.cq.tagging.TagManager` interface.

This means we need to determine what drives the list of tags returned by `com.day.cq.tagging.TagManager#getSupportedLanguageCodes()` and how to add supported languages to AEM's `TagManager`.

Global configuration in AEM is often contextual, likely a JCR property near the root of a content sub-tree, a Sling Context-Aware Configuration, or similar.

Let's take a guess and look at the root of the AEM Tags content tree: `/content/cq:tags`

This node has a JCR property named `languages`, of type `String[]`. This looks like a good candidate. Here's the value I found on my instance: `en, de, es, fr, it, pt_br, zh_cn, zh_tw, ja, ko_kr`

Extending this list appears to do the trick. I've added `de_de` to the list and the option *German (Germany)* showed up in the dropdown.

[image: Editing an AEM Tag. The same UI as in the question, with a new langauge, German(Germany) added to the end of the list]

For any custom locale code added this way, it **also** needs to be present in the global list under `/libs/wcm/core/resources/languages` or under its overlay under `/apps/wcm/core/resources/languages`